# PHP doesn't reload when page is linked to through a HREF

Tags: php, html

I tried explaining this before but its a weird one.

I have a page that relies on a variable from a database which can be altered on the page. This is got each time the code on the page is ran. However, when this page is accessed immediately after altering the variable then it didn't refresh.

So I did a little debugging and outputting the time onto the screen. So when I alter the variable on the page it redirects to another page. I enter through a href link on the index page. And the time is still previously. Why is it not refreshing the PHP code each time the page is loaded?

```
<?php
session_start();
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/testing/ticketsystem/server/databaseconfig.php");

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$clientstatus = $_SESSION['status'];

$id = $_GET['id'];

function statusBadge($status)
{
    switch($status)
    {
        case "user":
            return $status = "<span class='badge badge-user badge-pill badge-default'>User</span>";
            break;
        case "admin":
            return $status = "<span class='badge badge-user badge-pill badge-success'>Admin</span>";
            break;
        case !$status:
            return $status = "<span class='badge badge-user badge-pill badge-danger'>Error</span>";
            break;
    }
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <?php $pagetitle = "Ticket System"; require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/testing/ticketsystem/includes/head.php"); ?>

    <?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/testing/ticketsystem/includes/navbar.php"); ?>

    <body>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $active = $row['active'];
                echo (date("H-i-s",time()));
                echo $active;

                $ticketnav = "<ul class='nav nav-pills nav-justified'><li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='../../admin.php'>Go Back</a></li><li class='nav-item dropdown'><a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Admin Actions</a><div class='dropdown-menu'><a class='dropdown-item' href='activeticket.php?id=$id&active=1'>Close Ticket</a><a class='dropdown-item' href='activeticket.php?id=$id&active=0'>Open Ticket</a></div></li></ul>";

                if($active == 0)
                {
                    $ticketreply = "<div class='card'><div class='card-header'><p>Reply</p></div><div class='card-block'><form method='post' action='replyticket.php?id=$id'><div class='form-group'><label class='mr-sm-2' for='message'>Message</label><textarea name='message' class='form-control' rows='4'></textarea></div><button class='btn btn-success' type='submit'>Reply to this Ticket</button></form></div></div>";
                }
                elseif($active == 1)
                {
                    !$ticketreply;
                }
                $subject = $row['subject'];
                $department = $row['department'];
                $message = $row['message'];
                $created = $row['created'];
                $userid = $row['userid'];
                $createdformat = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($created));

                $tickethead = "<div class='card'><div class='card-header''><p>Support Ticket - #$id</p></div><div class='card-block'><p>Subject: $subject</p><p>Department: $department</p><p>Date: $createdformat</p></div></div>";

                $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$userid'";
                $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
                while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3))
                {
                    $username2 = $row3['username'];
                    $messagestatus = $row3['status'];

                    $ticketinital = "<div class='card'> <div class='card-header'><p><strong>Initial Message</strong></p><p>$username2 - " . statusBadge($messagestatus) . "</p><p>Date: $createdformat</p></div><div class='card-block'><p>Message: $message</p></div></div>";
                }

            }
            echo $ticketnav;
            echo $tickethead;
            echo $ticketreply;
            echo $ticketinital;

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ticketid = '$id' ORDER BY created DESC";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
            {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $userid = $row['userid'];
                    $message = $row['message'];
                    $created = $row['created'];
                    $createdformat = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($created));

                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$userid'";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
                    {
                        $username2 = $row2['username'];
                        $commentstatus = $row2['status'];

                        $ticketcomment = "<div class='card'><div class='card-header'><p>$username2 - ". statusBadge($commentstatus) ."</p><p>Date: $createdformat</p></div><div class='card-block'><p>Message: $message</p></div></div>";
                        echo $ticketcomment;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your code?

Comment: @Stretch0 I have included some code. I don't understand how the code could affect it loading as it seems like it waits for a certain time period to reload.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ ;) My guess is the browser is caching the page for a short period, or until you refresh in a particular way, and that's why the PHP code isn't run a second time. Try to create a [mcve], so that you can isolate the reload problem from the session, database, etc. You could probably delete 100 lines from this and still reproduce the problem, making it easier for both you and us to understand what's going on.

Comment: @IMSoP thats the problem here, it doesn't matter how little code I use the result of it only refreshing in this way is still a problem. Is there anyway to avoid the caching on particular sites?

Comment: Then post the *smallest* code which reproduces it, so we can understand what you've tested. Help us to help you.

Comment: @ParagonJenko try doing a cache refresh in your browser using Ctrl+F5 or Shift+F5 and see if it changes. If it does, then it's most likely browser cache problem. If it doesn't, then the problem is definitely from the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a caching issue on your browser. You could always try using headers to prevent caching:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

(I'm sure there's a million better ways to do this nowadays, feel free to google it find the proper way to do this).

Alternatively, add a "?rand=" to the URL you link back to when you alter the database ID - that way the browser will generally try and refetch the page since the random ID has probably changed :)